# How many tables altered by EXEC in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamicquery

I am changing the data type of columns in a few tables. and I have created a dynamic query for the same. Now I want to know the count of the tables which got altered actually by this query. I want to compare the expected and actual value if it matches then good else I need to run the rollback, Is there a way to do this?

**Query**:

```
USE FXecute

GO
DECLARE @ExpectedCounter INT=0, @ActualCounter AS INT=0

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #List
CREATE TABLE #List (Command varchar(max), OrderBy INT IDENTITY(1,1))
    
INSERT INTO #List 
 SELECT  
'ALTER TABLE ['+TABLE_SCHEMA+'].['+TABLE_NAME+'] ALTER COLUMN ['+COLUMN_NAME+'] DECIMAL(22,6)' AS 'Queries'
FROM FXecute.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE DATA_TYPE = 'DECIMAL' and (column_name  LIKE  '%amount%' or column_name  LIKE  '%amt%' OR column_name  LIKE  '%total%' 
OR column_name  LIKE  '%USD%') and TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE 'syncobj%'

SET @ActualCounter = @@ROWCOUNT;
PRINT 'Expected tables to be altered: ' + + CAST(@ActualCounter AS NVARCHAR(10)) 

DECLARE @sqlcmd VARCHAR(MAX);
    
 SET @sqlcmd = (
SELECT STRING_AGG(Command,';' + CHAR(10)) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY [OrderBy]) as cmd
FROM #List
)

PRINT @sqlcmd
EXEC(@sqlcmd);

IF (@ExpectedCounter = @ActualCounter)
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'All Good'
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Something wrong'
        --Rollback Script to be run
    END
GO
```

**Edit**:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table1] ALTER COLUMN [Column1] DECIMAL(22,6);
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table2] ALTER COLUMN [Column2] DECIMAL(22,6);
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table2] ALTER COLUMN [Column3] DECIMAL(22,6);
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table3] ALTER COLUMN [Column4] DECIMAL(22,6);
```

Comment: how this query work ? ```SELECT STRING_AGG(Command,';' + CHAR(10)) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY [OrderBy]) as cmd
FROM #List```

Comment: Tough to figure out from running that one query. Either split the long string to individual strings, put it in a cursor, and use a counter in a try-catch, OR save the previous datatype of the columns in a temp table, do the same for the later datatype, and check differences to see what was modified.

Comment: @Roshan it generates query like like 

`ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table1] ALTER COLUMN [Column1] DECIMAL(22,6);
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table2] ALTER COLUMN [Column2] DECIMAL(22,6);
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table2] ALTER COLUMN [Column3] DECIMAL(22,6);
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table3] ALTER COLUMN [Column4] DECIMAL(22,6);`

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis Is there an way to compare decimal(18,2) with decimal(22,6)? or decimal(19,4) with decimal(22,6)?

Comment: @viveknuna I Understand the Intention of the query. But I am getting syntax error. does this within Group only after 2016 version ? didn't find the correct resource

Comment: @Roshan it’s running without error for me. No, I’m running it normal old way.

Comment: As a side note, you are not quoting object names correctly. Instead of concatenating `[]` you need to use `QUOTENAME`. Also instead of using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` you should use `sys.columns`